# Compilation error in Eclipse in Kotlin + Java project, but project builds with Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, kotlin

This happens in a Java and maven project in Eclipse with a kotlin nature.

In this part of the code:

```
    val faces = figure.getFaces()       
    for (polygon in faces) {
        //...
```

I get the error below in eclipse, where `faces`, in the second line above, is underlined in red:

```
Cannot access class 'Polygon'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

The project is a mix of Java and Kotlin. The `figure` object is an instance of a Java class, while the `faces` are a set of type `Polygon` which is in a different project that is pure Kotlin (ie `Polygon` is a Kotlin type, in a separate Kotlin project).

This Kotlin project where `Polygon` is, is indeed in the classpath as a Maven dependency, and in fact used by the Java class of which `figure` is an instance.

I think the problem is in Eclipse, because I can build the project with maven successfully. It looks like either a bug in eclipse or a configuration issue.

I know it's strange to have a mix of Java and Kotlin. I simply started this project in Java and then decided to convert it to Kotlin gradually. So far I haven't had many issues but I'm aware that Kotlin tools and support in eclipse are not mature yet.

Comment: Are you using a recent version of Kotlin? Does Eclipse like it if you use PolygonKt instead of Polygon? If that's the problem, then you need to update your Eclipse config so that it's using a new version of Kotlin for its syntax checking / intelliensing.

Comment: The Kotlin plugin for eclipse hasn't been updated in months. Maybe bite the bullet and convert to IntelliJ for this project.

Comment: Can you post the full path of your `Polygen`-class starting from your project's home directory.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'm using v1.1.1. A more recent version won't work with the plugin. @guenhter I'm not sure what you mean, the class' project is another maven dependency and comes from my maven local repo

Comment: Ok, so `Polygin` is available via a Jar-file. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much of a proper solution: I converted my `Figure` class to Kotlin and the problem went away, but I can do that because I have full control on my project.

Possibly newer versions of the eclipse plugin won't generate this error or, as suggested in the comments, switching to IntelliJ IDEA is another option.